# Simple PHP Unique page hit counter stops after two counts?

Tags: php, unique, ip-address, counter, pageviews

```
 <?php  

 $countfile = 'counter.txt';
 $ipfile = 'ip.txt';



 function countint(){
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   global $countfile , $ipfile;


   if (!in_array($ip, file($ipfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))) {
   $current = (file_exists($countfile)) ? file_get_contents($countfile) : 0;
   file_put_contents($ipfile, $ip."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($countfile, ++$current);

   }



  }

  countint();
    $value =file_get_contents($countfile);

  ?>
```

This is this the count.php function included along with two file ip.txt and counter.txt

the count is not going past 2 hits

after two hits it stops recording  the ip address

Comment: i am echoing the $value on the page .

Comment: i can't see anything wrong with the script.. ever consider that you're not getting any more than 2 unique IP address' to the script...?  Perhaps the script is behind a proxy, load balancer, cache layer which is overriding the REMOTE_ADDR?

Comment: Change `!in_array` to `in_array` and you'll see it will increment. After data exists already of course.

Comment: So, you want a unique counter. I don't see why you would want to keep counting. The script does exactly as it should be doing. What is it that you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Ater opening the site from the third device ,the counter($value) still remains at 2;

Comment: Check to see if you're not using the same IP address as the other device(s). Plus, make sure both files are writeable. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Thanks Fred -ii- Its working after removing !in_array

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it. Would you like to see it? I can undelete it and you can accept if you wish.

Comment: It has been undeleted. It's slightly different but does the same effect.

Comment: But its not showing unique ip addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. I added an `elseif` and `in_array` condition `elseif (in_array...`

Sidenote: It makes sense that a `unique` hit counter stops after `1`, otherwise it wouldn't be unique.

If you want to keep counting them, you can give this a go. If it doesn't work as expected, let me know and I will try and modify it, or delete the answer altogether.

```
<?php  

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 $countfile = 'counter.txt';
 $ipfile = 'ip.txt';

 function countint(){
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   global $countfile , $ipfile;


   if (!in_array($ip, file($ipfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))) {
   $current = (file_exists($countfile)) ? file_get_contents($countfile) : 0;
   file_put_contents($ipfile, $ip."\n", FILE_APPEND);

    file_put_contents($countfile, ++$current);

   }


   elseif (in_array($ip, file($ipfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))) {
   $current = (file_exists($countfile)) ? file_get_contents($countfile) : 0;
   file_put_contents($ipfile, $ip."\n", FILE_APPEND);

    file_put_contents($countfile, ++$current);

   }

  }

  countint();
    $value =file_get_contents($countfile);

?>
```

Comment: it shouldn't increment if the same person refreshs the page twice .

Comment: @SACHINHD I can delete it then, and use what I originally stated in my comment bu using `in_array`. You could also use cookies.

Comment: Are ip adresses of two devices the same ,counter stops at 2 ?

Comment: its working but not solved with unique ip addresses?

Answer (score 0):

had to change the !in_array to if you want non-unique counter

```
<?php  

 $countfile = 'counter.txt';
 $ipfile = 'ip.txt';



 function countint(){
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   global $countfile , $ipfile;


    if (in_array($ip, file($ipfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))) {
    $current = (file_exists($countfile)) ? file_get_contents($countfile) : 0;
    file_put_contents($ipfile, $ip."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($countfile, ++$current);

    }



   }

    countint();
     $value =file_get_contents($countfile);

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  

$countfile = 'counter.txt';
$ipfile = 'ip.txt';



 function countint(){
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   global $countfile , $ipfile;


  if (!in_array($ip, file($ipfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))) {
  $current = (file_exists($countfile)) ? file_get_contents($countfile) : 0;
  file_put_contents($ipfile, $ip."\n", FILE_APPEND);
   file_put_contents($countfile, ++$current);

  }



   }

   countint();
  $value =file_get_contents($countfile);

   ?>
```

works fine for unique ip address counter....................
  if you to increment for every page view try the above answer with if else statement............

Comment: What's different about this new answer then the one I gave you and unaccepted? Besides the additional conditional statement in mine.